# Excel Formula to highlight cell(s) in the same column based on time difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, highlight

I want to highlight two cells if the cell under another cell is within 15 minutes in the same column only one row under the other. Essentially to highlight any 2 cells within the same column separated by 1 row above/under another one.

So if A1 is 1/28/2024 10:15:42 AM and A2 is 1/28/2024 11:02:03 AM, they are within 15 minutes apart, so highlight the two cells with that difference.

1/28/2024 10:15:42 AM

1/28/2024 11:02:03 AM

[image]

Ideally I would be also able to do gradient highlighting in the sense that any difference of more than 15 minutes would highlight the two cells red and anything between 10 and 15 minutes would be highlighted orange

This has plagued me and would greatly appreciate anyone's advice immensely.

tried a bunch of conditional formatting options with no luck, usually i've always been able to find a guide on this site or another for similar issues but this problem I'm having no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in Excel are integer values and times are decimal values. What you see like `1/28/2024 10:15:42 AM` Excel internally reads it as `45319,4275694444`

Knowing this, you just need to calculate the time difference between 2 dates. Because you are working in minutes, you need to know how many minutes a day got (it's 1440).

So if you do something like `ABS(Date1-Date2)*1440`you'll get time difference between 2 dates in minutes. We use `ABS` just to get the absolute value (it's easier this way)

[image]

I've created a CF rule based on this formula:

```
=OR(ABS(A2-A1)*1440<=15;ABS(A2-A3)*1440<=15)
```

*Ideally I would be also able to do gradient highlighting in the sense that any difference of more than 15 minutes would highlight the two cells red and anything between 10 and 15 minutes would be highlighted orange*

I see your point but I don't think it's possible. Think about this scenario:

[image]

Because you want to highligh **both** cells with time difference, in the image above 1st and 2nd dates should be orange (less than 10 minutes). But at the same time 2nd and 3rd should be red (10<time difference <15) but at the same time 3rd and 4th cells should be orange again (time diference < 10). It's kind of confusing to be honest.